# Switching To `innodb_file_per_table` In MySQL

Tags: mysql, database, innodb

If I turn on `innodb_file_per_table` (not currently active), will it destroy my existing tables?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, but you will need to do a sql dump and re-load or alternatively an optimize table before existing tables will be moved into their own files.

Of course as with any large architectural changes, make sure to nab a good backup before implementing the changes.

Comment: So, if I turned this on, then restarted mysql, I would not see any effect until I optimize?

Comment: That is correct.

Comment: Well, I should clarify, after a restart, any *new* tables will be implemented as file_per_table, but existing data will remain where it was previously.

Comment: Bonus note: once you reload into f-p-t mode, you'll have to manually clear ibdata1, as there's no way to shrink it.  Joy.  Needless to say, f-p-t is on by default in all my installations.

Comment: I just optimized all my tables with the new setting, however if/when i try to delete the old ibdata1 file, all my tables end up with 0 rows...  How can I get rid of the old file? (short of doing a dump/import)

Answer (score 1):

Even when you switch to innodb_file_per_table, the InnoDB tables that are inside ibdata1 must be extracted from ibdata1. Unfortunately, you cannot reclaim that space back.

You must **[overhaul the InnoDB infrastructure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3927690/howto-clean-a-mysql-innodb-storage-engine/4056261#4056261)** in order for innodb_file_per_table to work for you. @BMDan already mentioned this in his comment.